# Is "The U.S. decided sending Polish jets to Ukraine was too risky." grammatical?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, subjects

I saw a sentence on Twitter by Bloomberg Opinion writing like:

> The U.S. decided sending Polish jets to Ukraine was too risky.

I found two finite verbs here so I was thinking if the sentence was started by a that-clause functioning as the subject but the (that) was omitted:

> (That) the U.S. decided sending Polish jets to Ukraine was too risky.

But I'm not sure the (that) can be omitted in such case.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that the sentence cannot begin with "that" unless it is not in fact a sentence but part of some larger sentence.

> That the U.S. decided sending Polish jets to Ukraine was too risky.

is not a valid sentence. However it would be plausible to write:

> The U.S. decided that sending Polish jets to Ukraine was too risky.

But there is nothing wrong with the original sentence, nor with having two verb forms in close proximity to each other.

"The U.S." is the subject of "decided", and "[that] sending Polish jets to Ukraine was too risky." is the object. That is what the US had decided.

---

Bu the way

> I saw a sentence on Twitter by Bloomberg Opinion writing like:

is at best rewarded. It could be rephrased as:

> - I saw a sentence on Twitter by Bloomberg Opinion that read:
> - I saw a sentence on Twitter. Bloomberg Opinion wrote:
> - Bloomberg Opinion wrote on Twitter:

Please don't use "like" to mean "was". Like should mean "similar to" in this sort of context. Also please provide a more specific source than "on Twitter". If possible, given a link. Failing that, some way for othes to find the exact source.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It's a big help.